# facebook automate "post" (kind of...) from server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have following demand, from several customers :

They use an application that handles their inventory. Products in this inventory are manually created (text + pictures).
They synchronize this with a community website, where these products are visible.
In turn we read data from this community website to publish it on the customer's website. While we do this, the customers all want the new data (text & pictures) to be published on their Facebook page as well, so this is all done backend, by a Java Server application. In a perfect world, the synchronization/publishing would be made during nighttime... 
An app seems a good candidate for
 that...however, i'm wondering :

- What access shall the app request, do I need page access, or just post access ?
- Is it a violation of the rule that data cannot be automatically entered ?
- Do I need to make the application public in order to be able to use it ? (It will never be a public application as it's part of a commercial package)
- Of course, the customers don't mind giving any access to their FB page/user account, even their username /password if that can help...

Now any hints would be much appreciated-

Thanks in advance !

Comment: All interaction with the API needs an app. And authorization/granting permissions to post is done by implementing Facebook login. This question is too broad; suggest you start looking at the FB API documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Allow me te improve the question, and narrow it down a bit !